# Creating table outputs for PDF using R-markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

How can I create a formatted table for a PDF report using the `kable` function in Rmarkdown? Here is a MWE:

```
library(knitr)

df <- data.frame(bucket = 1:11,
                 value = c(-0.8125594, -0.7590050, -0.7189301, -0.7188391, -0.5047816,
                           -0.3439579, -0.4376782, -0.1300217, 0.9145718, 2.1844290,
                           4.8374356))

print(kable(df))
```

Output:

```
| bucket|      value|
|------:|----------:|
|      1| -0.8125594|
|      2| -0.7590050|
|      3| -0.7189301|
|      4| -0.7188391|
|      5| -0.5047816|
|      6| -0.3439579|
|      7| -0.4376782|
|      8| -0.1300217|
|      9|  0.9145718|
|     10|  2.1844290|
|     11|  4.8374356|
```

I am trying to format it for a PDF with a good visual like the picture attached:

[image: Output that I want to see in PDF]

Comment: Try [`kable`](http://127.0.0.1:14557/library/knitr/html/kable.html) from `knitr` R package.

Comment: Hi @Bustergun, I noticed you recently joined Stackoverflow.  I would recommend checking out the guides on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Also check this guide out on how to make a Minimal Working Example (MWE) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: To help you see what I mean by a minimal working example, I have edited the question to remove all the code which wasn't required. Hope it helps in your understanding :)

Answer (score 8):

There is no need to wrap the `kable` function with `print`. Here is a basic RMarkdown document which demonstrates it:

````
---
title: "MWE"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, message = FALSE}
library(knitr)

df <- data.frame(bucket = 1:11,
                 value = c(-0.8125594, -0.7590050, -0.7189301, -0.7188391, -0.5047816,
                           -0.3439579, -0.4376782, -0.1300217, 0.9145718, 2.1844290,
                           4.8374356))

kable(df)
```
````

[image]

> If you need to further customise the table, I would recommend checking out the `kableExtra` package: https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf

Comment: Good answer and great question edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tableHTML` to create flexible  HTML tables that can be styled using CSS.

```
library(tableHTML)
```

First, create a tableHTML with specific column-widths, the caption, and `'scientific'` theme (The default text align for that theme is `'center'`, this is why it needs to be changed to `'right'` using `add_css_conditional_column()` and `add_css_header()`). The last thing is to left align the caption and add a margin:

```
df %>% 
  tableHTML(rownames = FALSE,
            widths = c(50, 100),
            theme = 'scientific',
            caption = 'Table 4: Bucket Table') %>% 
  add_css_conditional_column(columns = 1:2,
                             conditional = "between",
                            between = c(-Inf, Inf),
                            css = list(c("text-align"),
                                       c("right !important"))) %>% 
  add_css_header(css = list(c("text-align"),
                           c("right !important")),
                 headers = 1:2) %>% 
  add_css_caption(css = list(c("text-align", "margin-bottom"),
                             c("left", "10px")))
```

This is what the result looks like:

[image: tableHTML_output]

Comment: So I'll just insert your codes below print(kable(df))?

Comment: i don't think you will need `print(kable(df))`

Comment: There was an error it says widths must have the same length as the columns. How can I remedy that?

Comment: how many columns do you have? in general, the `widths` argument of `tableHTML` is a numeric atomic vector  with column widths (with length equal to the number of columns). in the example you have two columns, hence `c(50, 100)`

Comment: I realized that my codes are inside a Function. Does that affect the output of the table?

Comment: you can return the `tableHTML` object, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks. My problem is already solved by your codes.